# Microsoft Teams call recording.....audio issues

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, bytebuffer, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Issue**
My code is based upon this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples).  When I capture audio it is extremely jittery/stuttery and sounds slightly 'sped up' as the playback duration is approx a quarter of the expected duration.

Code Snippet
Within my callhandler i have the following....my 'plan' is to try and hive off the received buffer asap to avoid any potential bottleneck(s) and then process the 'raw' bytes later and convert them into a WAV file.

```js
private async void OnAudioMediaReceived(object sender, AudioMediaReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (e.Buffer.IsSilence) return;
    var managedArray = new byte[e.Buffer.Length];
    Marshal.Copy(e.Buffer.Data, managedArray, 0, (int)e.Buffer.Length);
    using (var fs = new FileStream($"c:\\tmp\\myTelephoneCallAudio.raw",FileMode.Append))
    {
      fs.Write(managedArray, 0, managedArray.Length);
      fs.Close();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    throw;
  }
  finally
  {
    e.Buffer.Dispose();
  }
}
```

......then once the telephone call has ended i process the .raw file created above into a .wav by basically generating a wav file header and appending the wav content from the raw file.

**Expected behavior**
A clear and audible recording of the call lasting the expected duration.

Graph SDK(s) in use:

- Microsoft.Graph (Nuget) - v3.12.0
- Microsoft.Graph.Core (Nuget) - v1.21.0
- Microsoft.GraphCommunications.Calls (Nuget) - v1.2.0.1702
- Microsoft.GraphCommunications.Calls.Media (Nuget) - v1.2.0.1702
- Microsoft.GraphCommunications.Client (Nuget) - v1.2.0.1702
- Microsoft.GraphCommunications.Common (Nuget) - v1.2.0.1702
- Microsoft.GraphCommunications.Core (Nuget) - v1.2.0.1702

**Other information**
I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/331) but experience tells me I'm not going get a response.  But within that raised issue I attached is a zip with the 'mangled' wav.  This wav file is only 1m 25s but the call was 6.5 minutes long.

For a time I thought of the possibility of maybe the audio 'frames' were coming to me/being processed by me slightly out of sync/order....therefore i did try storing the frames in a dictionary where the key was the timestamp of the frame/buffer.....then i could order by the timestamp before attempting the conversion to the wav file.

Also after looking around [online](https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-file-size-calculator/) at expected wav file sizes, i.e. 10MB/min, etc.. it appears that the amount of data I'm capturing currently is a lot lower than expected for the assumed values, i.e. mono (1 channel), PCM 16K, with 32K sample rate, etc.

final note... every time when debugging OnAudioMediaReceived(), the buffer only has 640 bytes, meaning I'm appending at a rate of 640 per time...is this the same for anyone else who may be working on this?

Comment: We are checking it internally.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the [media calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts#media-session). Hope this helps you.